# Inserting rows with number of rows to insert as a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to insert rows with the number of rows to insert based on a variable. I am working backwards from the bottom to avoid messing up the row number. The code is below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub InsertRow()


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ColA As Range
Dim RowNo As Integer

Dim i As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ColA = ws.Range("A2:A944")

For i = 2 To ColA Step -1
RowNo = Range("B" & ":" & ColA.Row).Value

Rows(RowNo, 0).EntireRow.Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

Problem is with the line:

```
RowNo = Range("B" & ":" & ColA.Row).Value
```

I am not sure how the correct syntax to include variables in range dimensioning.

Comment: and what is your error msg? string + variable concating seems ok, but you have strange Range range definition

Comment: Type Mismatch on the opening of the For loop. What is the issue with the range definition?

Comment: Maybe it should be
`RowNo = Range("B" & ":" & i ).Value`
Will try after another macro finishes running.

Comment: so try to add For loop too please. And its abotu you trying to declare range as Range(B:4) (for example) and it should be atleast Range(B1:B4) so if you want to select value from single cell use this `Sheet.cells(ColA.row, "B").value`. Because that double colon (: this crap) means that you wana to specify range of multiple cells not only column and row

Comment: Right................everytime it's something stupid like this. Comprehensive answer, will test it out in a bit.

Comment: With your answer and some help from below, solved it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code.

1. ColA is a range rather than an integer.  While not a problem in itself, this means `For i = 2 To ColA` doesn't work.  The quick solution would be to use `For i = 2 To ColA.Rows.Count`; but,
2. It does make sense to work backwards, so this means you need to execute the For loop from the higher number to the lower number (`For i = ColA.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1`)
3. Inside the for loop `ColA.Row` will always return the first row of the range, 2 in this case. The concatenation used to specify the range resolves to "B:2", which isn't a valid address.
4. It is not clear why the code `RowNo = Range("B" & ":" & ColA.Row).Value` seems to be attempting to read a value from a range ("B2"?).  Is this supposed to be the cell that specifies how many rows to insert?  This is based on you statement that:

> with the number of rows to insert based on a variable

By setting the RowNo variable to the cell value and then using that value with `Rows(RowNo, 0).EntireRow.Insert`, the input value is actually used to determine the row before which the new rows will be inserted.  Was this the intention?  In this case, the code would insert a row in line 2 for every iteration of the loop (942 times).  So I will assume that the value from "B2" is supposed to be the number of rows to insert.

5. The line `Rows(RowNo, 0).EntireRow.Insert` doesn't need the column index.

Try this code:

Sub InsertRow()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ColA As Range
Dim RowNo As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ColA = ws.Range("A2:A944")

RowNo = ColA.Row

' Use cell B2 to set the number of rows to insert
Dim intAddRows As Integer
intAddRows = ws.Range("B2").Value

For i = 1 To intAddRows
    ws.Rows(RowNo).EntireRow.Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

Please note, however, that inserting rows at the start of the range `ColA` (so row 2 in this case) will move the input range `Range("B2")` down by the number of rows specified.  You will need to amend the code to pick up the number of rows from a more suitable place, perhaps like this: `intAddRows = InputBox("Number of rows to insert", "Set rows")`.

**UPDATE - To add the number of rows specified in column B:**

```
Sub insertRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RowNo As Integer
    Dim lastLine As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastLine = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For RowNo = lastLine To 2 Step -1
        For i = 1 To ws.Cells(RowNo, 2)
            ws.Rows(RowNo + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Next i
    Next RowNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Woops! Although you misunderstood my issue (the variable is not in B2, it is in every adjacent cell), I did learn a lot from this. My weakness is for next loops.

Comment: Ah, I'm with you now! Post updated to pick up the variable from column B.